# xcode build fail due to multiple commands producing the same file

Tags: xcode, react-native

I have a react native project that is using a 3rd party dependency.

The third party dependency has two filenames mentioned twice, one for device build and one for simulator build as far as I understand. It is shown in the picture below.
[image]

which is leader to the following error:

```
Showing All Errors Only
Multiple commands produce '/Users/{username}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{project-_name}-bzslvhzsciyfxdgcrhaxbhhllyaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/{package_name}/{package_name}framework/Headers/ModuleAppleHealth-Swift.h'
```

and the same error also for `ModuleAppleHealth`

Any idea how to solve this?